# Есть ли сокращённый формат if в python без else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

В python есть сокращённая форма записи `if`:

```
<True> if <условие> else <False>
```

но блок `else`  иногда категорически не нужен.

Ну например:

```
[x if x>5 for x in range(1,10)]
```

естественно выдаст ошибку.

Если я пишу в блоке `else` что-то, к примеру `else []` или `else None`, то оно в список пихает мне ненужные элементы, `else pass` здесь не проходит.

Вопрос: как то можно обойти эту конструкцию `if` и записать без `else`?

Comment: Вам что-то вроде `[x  for x in range(1,10) if x>5]` нужно?

Comment: Да, это вариант. Спасибо. Но всё таки, может что-то прописать после else возможно, чтобы конструкцию съело в варианте? [x if x>5 else <что-то> for x in range(1,10)]

Comment: Тернарный `if` (вида `a if condition else b`) возвращает или `a` или `b` в зависимости от условия. Вы хотите убрать ветку `else`, но чему тогда будет равно значение такого выражения в случае если условие == False?

Comment: что-то типа pass, т.е. ничего не делать

Comment: Ок, какое значение будет у переменной `bar` после `bar = 42 if False` ?

Comment: да я понимаю о чём вы, нужен блок возврата при else, но вот подумалось, может можно как то сделать, чтобы питон понимал, что возврат должен быть пустой, т.е. отсутствовать.

Comment: как то else pass или else continue, т.е. блок как бы есть, но возвращать ничего не нужно в случае else

Comment: Выражение так или иначе должно что-то возвращать (хотя бы `None`), иначе, к примеру, если мы его в условие засунем (`if (True if False): pass`) что будет происходить? Т.е. обычный `if/else` не возвращает ничего, и от него не требуется наличие ветки `else`, а `a if condition else b` это выражение, которое должно во что-то вычисляться в итоге, и опустить кусок `else` мы не можем.

Comment: Я наверное слишком высокого мнения о гибкости питона, он иногда такие сюрпризы преподносит, что совсем не ожидаешь. Вот думал, что может быть и тут можно что-то придумать :) О "сюрпризах" питона можно к примеру тут почитать: https://habrahabr.ru/post/207988/

Comment: Кстати, а ведь в вашем варианте [x for x in range(1,10) if x>5] нет блока else

Comment: @Oleg да, потому что это не блок if-else, а часть синтаксиса генератора.

Answer (score 7):

Как уже отметил в комментариях Владимир, `<True> if <условие> else <False>` — это функция, которая обязана вернуть какое-либо значение.

Но ваша задача — выделить из списка элементы, удовлетворяющие условию — имеет как минимум два решения.

Можно использовать генератор с условием:

```
[x for x in range(1, 10) if x < 5]
```

То же в общем виде:

```
[function1(item) for item in iterable if function2(item)]
```

Можно использовать [встроенную функцию `filter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter). Она принимает функцию для фильтрации и фильтруемый список, а возвращает итератор. Чтобы получить список, мы инициализируем `list()` от возвращённого нам итератора:

```
list(filter(lambda x: x < 5, range(1, 10)))
```

Стоит заметить, что генератор более функционален, т.к. позволяет фильтровать по значению одной функции (например, `x < 5`), а вернуть в генерируемый список значение другой функции (например, `x ** 2`):

```
[x ** 2 for x in range(1, 10) if x < 5]
```

Comment: TODO: написать про генераторы, итераторы и `yield`.

Comment: Не используйте filter(), если приходится lambda определять. Используйте list comprehension вместо этого.

Answer (score 2):

[list-comprehensions](http://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/)

```
for x in range(1, 10):
    if x > 5:
        B.append(x+1)

B = [x+1 for x in range(1, 10) if x > 5]

for x in range(1, 10):
    if x > 5:
        B.append(x+1)
    else:
        B.append(x+2)

B = [x+1 if x > 5 else x+2 for x in range(1, 10)]

for x in range(1, 10):
    if x < 9:
        if x > 5:
            B.append(x+1)
        else:
            if x == 1:
                B.append(x+2)
            else:
                B.append(x+3)

B = [x+1 if x > 5 else x+2 if x == 1 else x+3 for x in range(1, 10) if x < 9]

for x in range(1, 10):
    if x < 9:
        for y in range(x+1):
            if x == y:
                B.append((x+2, y+2))

B = [(x+2, y+2) for x in range(1, 10) if x < 9 for y in range(x+1) if x == y]
```

Comment: Зачем везде `print` внутри генераторов и циклов? Автору нужно получить массив, а не напечатать.

Comment: Не используйте list comprehension, если вам результат не нужен, как в случае с print() функцией, которая всегда None возвращает. Достаточно явных циклов. Для примера в вопросе, следует использовать выражение, которое числа возвращает